# PyCharm Professional - type hinting error

Tags: pycharm

I've recently switched from PyCharm Community Edition to PyCharm Professional and I believe there's something wrong with the type hinting system of PyCharm Professional.

For example, if I'm using the function `map()`, I get the following hint from PyCharm Community Edition, which appears to be reasonable:

[image]

And here is what I get from PyCharm Professional, which does not look right:

[image]

I don't believe this is the intended behaviour. This issue appears to impact all functions that take iterable inputs.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so, has anyone found a way to fix this?

Many thanks!

EDIT:
My PyCharm Professional version: 2017.1

My PyCharm Community Edition version: 2016.3

Comment: Do Community Edition and Professional have same version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm started to show types in parameters hints in 2017.1 version.

Parameter types for builtin functions are taken from pyi-stubs which are available [here (Py2)](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2/__builtin__.pyi) and [here (Py3)](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi).

`map` function has signatures which are shown on your screenshot. So there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Great, thank you, I thought that It didn't look right.